# php query sql error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query in a php page:

```
 q('INSERT INTO books (book_id,user_id,location_id,class_id,course_id,email,isbn,title,author,price,condition,sharing,sold,reporting,date) VALUES ("'.$row['id_libro'].'","'.$row['id_utente'].'","'.$row['id_sede'].'","0","0","'.$row['email'].'","'.$row['isbn'].'","'.$row['titolo'].'","'.$row['autore'].'","'.$row['prezzo'].'","'.$row['stato'].'","'.$row['condivisione'].'","'.$row['venduto'].'","'.$row['segnalazione'].'","'.$row['data'].'")');
```

but when I run the code I get this error:ù

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition,sharing,sold,reporting,date) VALUES ("122","0","1","0","0","DOTS@hotma' at line 1
```

but I don't understant, I check all the apices and I didn't find the error. Someone can help me?
Thanks

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html   `condition` is reserved.

Comment: @MarcB ehm...I don't understand...can you explain me better?

Comment: @MarcB sorry,now I have understood